# Issue with showing the name in a row on a textfield in the next viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My issue is this...when I click on a row of my tableview, I have to go to another screen. In that screen, there is a textfield where the value in the row(in previous screen) has to be assigned to a textfield..for that I am doing this..

```
editTextField.text = modelArray[index!]
```

But it shows this error…`’Cannot assign value of type 'NSManagedObject' to type 'String?'’`

Also `modelArray` is of type `NSManagedObject`.

What should be done in this case...?

Comment: show your modelArray initialization code

Comment: what do you get when print(modelArray[index!])???

Comment: @DHEERAJ this was what I got...data: {
    categoryId = 2;
    categoryName = test2;
})

Comment: try `editTextField.text = modelArray[index!].categoryName`

Comment: @Gagan_iOS this is how modelArray is initialized...detailViewController.modelArray = people

Comment: you need to parse the data and get the result to textfield...

editTextField.text = data["categoryName"]

Comment: can you please show how did you create modelArray?

Comment: @DHEERAJ that's what I am a bit confused with....as to how I can parse the data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a classic type mismatch. You have `NSManagedObject` but the label expects `String`

Two options:

- If you are using `NSManagedObject` subclass and `modelArray` is declared as an array of that type

  ```
  let item =  modelArray[index!]
  editTextField.text = item.categoryName
  ```
- If you **don't** use `NSManagedObject` subclass

  ```
  let item =  modelArray[index!]
  editTextField.text = item.value(forKey:"categoryName") as? String
  ```

In any case why is `index` an optional?. An optional index type is nonsense because it doesn't prevent an out-of-range exception.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @vadian...just what I was looking for...:)

Comment: Also, @vadian, there is another small issue..I am not able to give like so..self.people.append(self.newCategories)...because people is an NSManagedObject and newCategories is a String.

Comment: That's another type mismatch, but the information is not sufficient to suggest a solution. Please ask a new question and give much more information about the context.

Answer (score 0):

’Cannot assign value of type 'NSManagedObject' to type 'String?'’

This show's you are trying to use coredata value to show in the textfiled. You can do these things

1. Pass the value from tableview didselect method to controller and show that in the textfield (the value in the cell definitely be a string)
2. Create Textfield globally in your nextviewcontroller and change its value in tableview did select delegate method